# How do I change the custom URL domain name for my community I deploy my community from the sandbox to the production org?

Tags: customer-community

How do I change the custom URL domain name  for my community after deploying my community from the sandbox to the production org?

> https://dreamson-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/customerlogin

This is the URL for the community  that I created

Is it possible to change this URL to :

> https://website.in/customerlogin

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change the domain url in your production org, below are the steps :-

1.)Add the custom URL to Salesforce

2.)Generate a Certificate Signing Request from Salesforce

3.)Create a CNAME (Alias) record in your domain name registrar

4.)Generate an SSL certificate in your domain name registrar

5.)Upload the SSL certificate to Salesforce

or further you can take reference with this link --
http://thinkaholics.com/salesforce/how-to-add-a-custom-url-to-salesforce-communities/

Hope this will helpful to you.